# How can I force Python to navigate to a web page and print all anchors (a-html)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to take some data off an intra-net site at work.  I am testing the code below, which looks fine me, but it almost seems like it is going to the wrong URL.  If I right-click on the page and click 'View Page Source', I can see a bunch of links (anchors) that I want to scrape from, but what Python is actually printing out is completely different from what I'm seeing in 'View Page Source'.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from lxml import html
import urllib.request

REQUEST_URL = 'https://corp-intranet-internal.com/admin/?page=0'
response = requests.get(REQUEST_URL, auth=('fname.lname@gmail.com', 'my_pass'))
xml_data = response.text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(REQUEST_URL)
delay = 5 # seconds
soup = bs(html_page, "lxml")
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

I tested the same idea, using Selenium, and I'm getting results that don't match the 'View Page Source'.  Any idea what could be wrong here?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you try printing the full html result to see what page you ended up on in python? I'm not entirely sure why you switched to `urllib` after starting with `requests`: `urllib` doesn't have any of your authentication information, so I would assume that `urllib` is returning a page/response asking you to login.